# When creating teams, are there any differences if i add the user from sharepoint site or from Office 365 group or from MS Teams

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, administration, office-365-groups, microsoft-teams

Inside our office 365 tenant, i created a new MS Teams, as follow:-
[image]

which also created new office 365 group + sharepoint modern team site.
Now to add members or owners to the MS Teams, i found those 5 ways:-

1. using the MS Team desktop app i can add members and owners.
2. i login to office 365 admin center >> Office 365 Groups >> i can add members and owners.
3. login to the sharepoint site >> click on "Site Permission" >> "Invite People" >> "add members to group">>i can add members and owners.
4. Inside the office 365 admin center >> MS Teams >> i can add members and owners.
5. Finally if i went to office 365 admin center >> Active users >> click on a user >> Edit the user >> Edit "Group memberships" >>i can add the user to office 365 group.

so all of the above will add the user to the Office 365 either as Owner or member , and as so will grant the user access to Teams and the sharepoint site. **But my question if adding users using the above 5 approaches will be exactly the same? or some approaches will not be the same as others?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the approaches you outlined are identical. If you add them to the Office 365 Group in the various ways you can do so, they will have the appropriate access to Teams, SharePoint, and any other associated applications (Planner, Yammer, Stream, etc.).

Comment: thanks for the reply.. so all the 5 approaches are technically the same ?

Comment: Yes, they are. And there are more ways to manage this, as well (via Outlook/OWA, for example).

Answer (score 1):

Just to add, if you want to add 'Visitors' in your SharePoint site, then adding them in the O365 group will not work. Adding users to O365 group will give them default 'Member' access, i.e. contributor permission in SharePoint.

[image]

In this case, you need to click on the 'Advanced Permission settings' from the bottom of the 'Site Permission' popup. It will land you to the classic permission management page for the SharePoint site, where you should see 3 groups specific to that SharePoint site, Owner, Member and Visitor. Owners from corresponding Office365 group is added as 'Owner' to the site and members to the Member group. Here you can add people/ group in the 'Visitor' group, to give them 'reader' permission.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the summary, although did not answer my question :) btw adding a user as an owner inside office 365 will not define the user as owner on the sharepoint site, as members and owners of the office 365 group will be members on sharepoint...

Comment: @SharePointTestDev your question was already answered by Trevor, I just wanted to add information related to adding visitors to your SharePoint site. Also, Office 365 group owners are definitely having full control over corresponding SharePoint site. They might not be added under the SharePoint group for site Owners like the Members, but you can check that by using 'Check Permissions' link in the permission management page (_layouts/15/user.aspx).

Comment: @SharePointTestDev Please check this link where I've added screenshots to demonstrate the permission management using O365 group membership levels : https://1drv.ms/w/s!AqttZUXkcjGvd8qtbsGgpk6dKL4?e=GfkzgK